# Increment a variable each time a script

Tags: r, increment

I have an R script that runs automatically. Each time it runs a variable in the script should be incremented. As a sample, I have the following R script:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
lab0 <- xxx(ffff,(hhh))
zzzzzzz
```

When the above script runs **lab0** should be incremented to **lab1**. When it runs again to **lab2**, when it runs again to **lab3** etc.
Any help on how this can be done would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The above sample code is in a file.

Comment: This is running on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure that the following is what you want.
This script will increment `lab0` to `lab1, ...` every time it is run.

```
## Not run
#rm(list = ls())

xxx <- function(x, y) x + y
ffff <- 1; hhh <- 2
lab0 <- xxx(ffff, hhh)

# increment counter
i <- as.integer(sub("lab", "", grep("lab", ls(pattern="lab")[length(ls(pattern="lab"))], value = TRUE))) + 1
#assign the value of lab0 to the new lab
assign(paste0("lab", i), lab0)

ls(pattern = "lab")    # check to see if it worked
```

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid. How would I use your script? Like, where do I give the name of my script? I assume your script is an R script?

Comment: @user1907031 In the question you say you *have an R script that runs automatically*. Try it with this one and see if this is what you need. If you run this script several times you will see `lab0`, then `lab1`, then `lab2`, etc. But like I said, I don't quite understand the question. If this is **not** what you need, please say it and I'll delete it.

Comment: @user1907031 I am assuming that the script is run multiple times in the same R session.

Comment: I have an R script which downloads tweets at regular intervals. This is done by using Crontab to run the script. The R script saves the tweets as an R object with the name lab0, this is when the script runs the first time. When this script runs the second time the lab0 object will be overwritten. To prevent this I need a way to increment lab0 to lab1. When the script runs a third time lab1 should be incremented to lab2, etc. So this is why I need another script that will increment lab0. This second script to do the incrementation will also be run by Crontab. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried the script it increments from 0 to 1 only, and not beyond.